# java.lang.Double cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap error showing after using react-native-gifted charts

Tags: react-native, build

While using react-native-gifted charts my application suddenly stops working and the error being shown is
java.lang.Double cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap.

This error showing after using react-native-gifted charts

Answer (score 3):

for me i fixed the issue by using specific version of react-native-svg
npm install react-native-svg@12.1.0

Comment: works for me. error when using react native qr code